# Message not being sent to the error queue

Tags: masstransit

I am using MassTransit version 2.9.2 with MSMQ.

I am working on testing the error handling, and am expecting the process to attempt to send my message 5 times and then place the message within the error queue.

The message is being retried the 5 times, but then just disappears.  Can anyone explain why the message isn't being sent to the error queue.

My consumer:

```
public class OrderConsumer : Consumes<SAPOrder>.Context
{
    public ISapServiceRepository SapServiceRepository { get; set; }

    public void Consume(IConsumeContext<SAPOrder> message)
    {
        try
        {
            // Send the message to SAP
            this.SapServiceRepository.SendOrder(message.Message);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }       
    }
}
```

I am using AutoFac to register the service bus and consumers.

```
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Register(c => ServiceBusFactory.New(sbc =>
        {
            // other configuration options
            sbc.UseMsmq(
                configurator => configurator.VerifyMsmqConfiguration());

            sbc.UseXmlSerializer();
            sbc.ReceiveFrom("msmq://localhost/orders");
            sbc.Subscribe(x => x.LoadFrom(c.Resolve<ILifetimeScope>()));
            sbc.EnableMessageTracing();
            sbc.UseLog4Net();
        })).As<IServiceBus>()
            .SingleInstance();

        if (this.registerConsumers)
        {
            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(this.GetType().Assembly)
                .Where(t => t.Implements<IConsumer>())
                .PropertiesAutowired(PropertyWiringOptions.AllowCircularDependencies)
                .AsSelf();

            builder.RegisterType<SapServiceRepository>()
                .As<ISapServiceRepository>()
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope()
                .WithProperty("Username", "xxxxxxxxxxxx")
                .WithProperty("Password", "xxxxxxxxxxxx")
                .WithProperty("CountryId", "xxxxxxxxxxx")
                .WithProperty("UseRequestLogging", true)
                .PropertiesAutowired(
                    PropertyWiringOptions.PreserveSetValues | PropertyWiringOptions.AllowCircularDependencies);
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is there a permissions issue preventing the _error queue from being created? Is the queue showing up in the Message Queuing MMC pane? The message should end up in the error queue after five failures, just as you expect. There are unit tests that verify this as well that are passing. Is something reading from the error queue that might be consuming the message?

Answer (score 0):

The error queue has been created.

I don't think that there is anything reading from the error queue, since I have posted the original message I created a new consumer for Fault.  This is being called once the 5 retrys have been attempted.

Within the fault consumer I am then getting the original failed message and can then forward onto the error queue using the code

```
public class OrderFaultConsumer : Consumes<Fault<SAPOrder>>.Context
{
    public ILog Logger { get; set; }

    public void Consume(IConsumeContext<Fault<SAPOrder>> message)
    {
        // need to send to the error queue
        var errorQueue = message.Bus.GetEndpoint(message.Endpoint.ErrorTransport.Address.Uri);
        errorQueue.Send(message.Message.FailedMessage);
    }
}
```

The message is then visible within the error queue.

This all seems to work, but in my mind is a bit of a hack!

Just to point out that I am not using Multicast, or the subscription service.  My code that adds the message to the queue is doing a send rather than a publish.